# Filter one sided table in many to one relationship

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like two measures that SUM the Sales[Value] for all the Sales[ID] that have a specific StatusID in SalesStatus.

One that can filter on Sales[Date], and one that can filter on SalesStatus[statusDate]

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHWMd.png)

Regards,
Anders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this scenario I would consider modifying your model to have only two tables by combining what appears to be two FACT tables (sales, sales status). Depending on what your data consists of I would either UNION the two tables after joining and then treat the date in your Sales table as another status date (i.e. shipped complete or sale finished, whatever that date represents) OR I would join the two tables and have two relationships to the date table.

This will create a duplicated data issue as you will ideally result in having the value column in your final fact table. If you go with the union option, you can force the user to select a single sales status effectively removing the sales duplication. If you end up with two connections to the date table, you can use the USERELATIONSHIP() function to write the two different sales measures, and the one that uses the date from the Sales table will need some clever tricks to ensure the data does measure does not duplicate. I would try to UNION the tables though.

For more details, I would research what's referred to as SEMI-ADDITIVE fact tables in datawarehousing. There is a great article from SQL BI on the subject. I have tried setting up models like you diagrammed and even if I could get them to work through intense DAX measures, they would produce unexpected results and have poor performance. I find the Semi additive fact table pattern to be a much cleaner solution once you get passed the data duplication that results.

Example:
[image: Two Model Change Options]